# What's this kanji in the sentence?

Tags: translation, kanji

[image: Text]

I thought as far as 今夜は？サベ
But sabe doesn't seem like a thing?

Comment: Could you edit your question and upload the picture again using the image upload button (this way it will not be deleted)? Otherwise nobody will understand what this question was really about.

Comment: The image sharing service OP used says images last for at least 6 months, so OP probably deleted the image by hand... @Earthliŋ Feel free to delete this question if the image remains missing.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's [寒サバ](https://www.pref.mie.lg.jp/suigi/hp/78573017344.htm) (winter mackerel), but this is indeed poorly written...

Comment: 「バ」じゃなくて「ベ」に見えてしまいますね

Comment: @AeonAkechi 「寒」も「サ」も「バ」も全部読みづらいので、これは「寒サバ」という言葉を知らないと難しいですね…

Comment: Thank you! I think this is correct, at first I thought it was some dialect with 「べ」